# Keep rows together when sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I like to sort my Excel worksheet with VBA. But instead of just sorting the rows I want to keep certain rows together when I perform the sort.

In my file I have certain rows that must be always together in the same order as started. Together they form a "Project". Every project has 33 rows. In the second row in column B of each project, a project number is placed.
So to do this I made a helper column (A). And in that column I wrote a formula like this:

```
     =B19&"BG"
```

This specific formula is placed in the upper cell of a project. the B19 cell is where the project number of that project is located. "BG" is added to the upper cell to get the right way of sorting and that must be descending. So the cell underneath that cell is

```
         =B19&"BF"
```

and so on and on.

So the problem I have is that for some reason sometimes (not always) Excel is messing it up. The rows are then all over the place but I can not find any reason for it.

Is there another/ better way to sort the file and keep those rows together?

This is the code I use for sorting the file:

```
Private Sub SortPersonalPlanner()

If Sheets("planning").AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planning").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planning").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
    
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Planning").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$17:$DM$99999").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add screenshot of a sample data. I don't think you need VBA for sorting if you are ok with a helper column

Comment: Indeed i made two helper columns now. One that's sorts the project numbers and a second column that gives the order for the rows in each project.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to keep certain rows together when sorting with Excel's built in sort method.

The only workaround can be to write your personal sort method that keeps track of that, or to have a helper column that provides some **constant** data to sort with and no formulas. Formulas will change their values if you sort, because the data in the cells they refer to changes you it gets re-ordered on a sort.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did some testing around earlier with just the project number in the helper column. I placed in each cell the value of the project number and hit sort. Excel was not messing it up but I'm unsure if this always works. Further, I have no experience with writing my own sorting method.